# How to get the ID of each element?

Tags: jquery, input

I have multiple input with different IDs and I'm searching for a way to find the ID of each one. I made [a pen here](https://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/ExyEoRe) but, basically, here is what I've tried so far.

```js
// DISPLAYS ALL ID's
var id = [];
$('input').each(function() {
  id.push($(this).attr('id'))
})

// DISPLAYS THE FIRST ID
var ids = $('.content div').find('input').attr('id');

// DISPLAYS THE FIRST ID
var i = $('input').get(0).id

// APPEND LABEL
var customlabel = $('<label>input ID = #' + i + '</label>');
$('.content div').append(customlabel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div><input type='radio' id="one" /></div>
  <div><input type='radio' id="two" /></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div><input type='radio' id="three" /></div>
  <div><input type='radio' id="four" /></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div><input type='radio' id="five" /></div>
  <div><input type='radio' id="six" /></div>
</div>
```

My goal is just to get the ID of each input separately. But with this *var i*, I only get the ID of the first input ("one" on each line). When I use .each(), all IDs are displayed together (one,two,three,four,five,six).

```
  var id=[];
  $('input').each(function(){
    id.push($(this).attr('id'))
  })
```

My jQuery knowledge is limited and I already spent hours trying different solutions found on stack, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected result? How is the markup supposed to look like at the end?

Comment: From your example it looks like `<label>` is not the correct element. It's supposed to be wrapped around an `<input />` element or to be linked with an `<input />` element via its `for="..."` attribute

Comment: Yes, the label is linked via its "for=''" attribute, but I wanted to make this question as basic as possible. I got 2 working solutions yet (from Pete and Thong) so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
$(".content div").each(function(){
    let id = $("input", this).attr("id");
    $(this).append("<label>"+id+"</label>");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why, when I used .each() it displayed all IDs on each line. What's the difference with your snippet? Anyway, your solution works great so thanks a lot.

Comment: you mean this?:<br/>

**var id=[];
  $('input').each(function(){
    id.push($(this).attr('id'))
  })**<br/>

your code word like this:<br/> 
**#1: declare an empty array named id**<br/> 
**#2: for each input, put the input's id to the end of the id array**<br/> 

that why they are print out all the same time - hope it clear.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks again for your help Thong. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to add a label of the id after the input, you need to do that in your each loop (rather than trying to put them all in an array and append that after the each has finished)

```js
$('input').each((index, input) => {
  const $thisInput = $(input);  // current input
  
  $thisInput.after(`<label for="${input.id}">input id = #${input.id}</label>`);  // add a label after the current input
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div><input type='radio' id="one" /></div>
  <div><input type='radio' id="two" /></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div><input type='radio' id="three" /></div>
  <div><input type='radio' id="four" /></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div><input type='radio' id="five" /></div>
  <div><input type='radio' id="six" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks a lot for your help. I will have to choose between your answer and Thong answer now because both are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each of the input using `$.each`, then [`create a DOM element`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) `label` and find the [`parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) of the current input element and [`append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) the newly created label into it.

```js
$(function() {
  $.each($('input[type="radio"]'), function(key) {
    const label = $('<label/>').text(`input ID = #${key + 1}`);
    $(this).parent().append(label);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div><input type='radio' id="one" /></div>
  <div><input type='radio' id="two" /></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div><input type='radio' id="three" /></div>
  <div><input type='radio' id="four" /></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div><input type='radio' id="five" /></div>
  <div><input type='radio' id="six" /></div>
</div>
```