# Get id of each element when scroll to top in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I want to get id of the section element when it reaches the top. Something similar has been done with [jquery already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64611695/how-to-get-the-id-of-each-element) but I want same with Angular. I tried in similar way but not getting success.

```js
/*let content = document.getElementsByClassName('scrollable');
      this.listener = this.renderer2.listen('window', 'scroll', (e) => {
        
        let elementPos = el.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
    
        
        var el = Array.prototype.forEach.call(content, (el)=>{
            // console.log(el.id, el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom, parseInt(el.clientHeight))
            if(el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom >= parseInt(el.clientHeight)) {
              console.log({el})
            }
        })
        
        */
```

```css
section {background: #ccc; height: 100vh;};
section:nth-child(odd) {background: red}
```

```html
<section class="scrollable" id="scroll1"> Scroll1 </section>
<section class="scrollable" id="scroll2"> Scroll2 </section>
<section class="scrollable" id="scroll3"> Scroll3 </section>
<section class="scrollable" id="scroll4"> Scroll4 </section>
<section class="scrollable" id="scroll5"> Scroll5 </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this [stackblitz](https://angular-ivy-2tkcpg.stackblitz.io).

I stored `offsetTop` of sections and added a listener for scroll on window and checked if it reached the threshold.

Comment: The link is not accessible though. Its throwing some console error. Could you please post the code here.

Comment: I manage to find your profile on stackblitz and corrected the code. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to make it work on my own with little bit of experiment. Below code might help. Thanks

```
      let content = document.getElementsByClassName('scrollable');
      // let windowTop = window.scroll.offset()
      this.listener = this.renderer2.listen('window', 'scroll', (e) => {
        
        
          let scrollY = this.windowRef.nativeWindow.pageYOffset;
           let landingPage = Array.prototype.filter.call(content, (el)=>{
            //  console.log(el.id, scrollY, el.getBoundingClientRect().top)
              return scrollY > (el.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset - 80);
            })

            // console.log({landingPage})
            console.log(landingPage.at(-1).id)           
      
        });
```

.....edited.....

I tried correcting @Mahdi Zarei code and got some result. [stackblitz demo](https://angular-ivy-46tdmb.stackblitz.io/)

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // @ts-ignore
    const sections : any = Array.from(
      document.getElementsByClassName('scrollable') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>
    ).map((section) => [section.id, section.offsetTop]);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (ev) {
      let foundIndex = 0;
      sections.forEach((sec, index) => {
        if (document.scrollingElement.scrollTop >= sec[1]) {
          foundIndex = index;
        }
      });
      document.getElementById('el').innerText = sections[foundIndex][0];
    });
  }
}
```